# ¿Cómo envío argumentos de una pagina a otra? Flutter

Tags: json, firebase, rest, flutter

Estoy intentando enviar los argumentos de una page a otra en mi app, funcionó con una página, pero ahora no lo hace con otra, aquí funciona bien el código y muestra bien el listado.

```
      Widget _crearListadoParticipantes() {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Participantes>>(
      future: eventosProvider.cargarParticipantes(evento, participantes),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if ( snapshot.hasData ) {
          final participantes = snapshot.data;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: participantes.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              return _crearParticipante(context, participantes[i]);
            }
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError){
          return Center(child: Text("${snapshot.error}"));
        } else {  
          return Center( child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _crearParticipante(BuildContext context, Participantes participantes) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontFamily: "Lato_LightItalic",
              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
              fontSize: 18.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
            ),
            children: [
              TextSpan(text: '     '+'${participantes.numero}',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
                )
              ),
              TextSpan(text: "           "),
              TextSpan(text: '${participantes.apellido}')
            ],
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'destalleParticipante', arguments: evento),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Esta es la page donde quiero recibir los argumentos del elemento al que le doy onTap:

```
          @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        final EventoModel eventoData = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
        if ( eventoData != null ) {
          evento = eventoData;
        }
          print(participantes.nombre);
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(0),
            child: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Color(0xFF249FE2),
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body:  Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                _encabezadoParticipante(context, AssetImage("assets/icon/info_corredor.png"), participantes),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

      Widget _backBottom() {
return FloatingActionButton(
  elevation: 0.0,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  child: Icon(
    Icons.arrow_back,
    size: 45.0,
    color: Colors.black,
  ),
  onPressed: (){
    Navigator.pop(context);
  },
);
```

}

```
      Widget _encabezadoParticipante(BuildContext context, AssetImage image, Participantes participantes) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.grey[600],
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                _backBottom(),
                Flexible(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(participantes.nombre,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      maxLines: 3,
                      softWrap: true,
                      style: TextStyle(                
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontFamily: "Lato",
                        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                        fontSize: 30.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Image(image: image,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

He intentado algunos métodos que encontré en la documentación de Flutter y otros en diferentes cursos y vídeos en línea pero aun así cuando en la segunda page quiero mostrar los datos que necesito estos aparecen como null, y cuando hago la depuración en esta parte del código todos los datos empiezan a mostrarse en null:

> `final EventoModel eventoData = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
>           if ( eventoData != null ) {
>             evento = eventoData;
>           }`

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en que estas enviando como argumento la variable `evento` la cual no es accesible por `_crearParticipante` puede agregar un tercer argumento para que reciba el evento o pasar el objeto `participantes` a la ruta.

```
Widget _crearParticipante(BuildContext context, Participantes participantes, EventoModel evento) {
 ....
 onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'destalleParticipante', arguments: evento),
}
```

Ahora cabe recordar que `evento` no se desde donde se esta instanciado, ya que lo estas usando tambien en `_crearListadoParticipantes()` ya que dices que funciona correctamente entonces agregar el tercer argumento al widget y pasarlo en el `itemBuilder` debería funcionar.

```
    Widget _crearListadoParticipantes() {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Participantes>>(
      future: eventosProvider.cargarParticipantes(evento, participantes),
      ...
      ...
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              return _crearParticipante(context, participantes[i], evento);
        }
    ....
```

Comment: Hola! la data si la esta enviando a la otra page, pero cuando pasa por aquí todo para a ser null: 
    if ( eventoData != null ) {
      evento = eventoData;
    }

Comment: Como explico en la respuesta el esta enviado `arguments: evento` , pero `evento` no esta en ninguna parte del widget `_crearParticipante` por lo tanto va ha ser `null`. Intenta enviar por ejemplo `arguments: participantes` si no da `null` pues ya vale.